# В.п. числительных и одушевленных существительных

Tags: числительные

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно изменяются в 
винительном падеже составные числительные и связанные с ними 
одушевлённые существительные?
Например: как правильно сказать  "вижу 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 женщин и котов. "
Хочется сказать  "я вижу двадцать четыре женщины"...
На одном сайте мне ответили "
Стилистически нейтральны формы: вижу 22, 23, 24 женщины; вижу 22, 23, 24 кота; вижу 25, 26 женщин; вижу 25, 26 котов.
В разговорной речи допустимо: вижу 22, 23, 24 женщин; вижу 22, 23, 24 котов."
Мне всё ещё не понятно. Значит ли это, что в стилистически нейтральной форме с однозначными числами тоже можно говорить: вижу две, три, четыре женщины, два, три кота, вместо двух, трёх, четырёх женщин, котов?
А в разговорной речи: вижу 22 женщин окончания Р.п. принимает только последнее число двадцать двух женщин или по правилам оба должны меняться (двадцати двух)? Что-то я запуталась совсем...
Спасибо!

Comment: я уверен, что с правилами вы сами можете ознакомиться, а на мой взгляд в В.п. составные числительные при одушевлённых сущ-ных склоняются по парадигме неодушевлённых; если ***вижу двадцать двух/трёх котов/женщин*** ещё как-то звучит, хоть и плохо, то ***вижу двадцать четырёх котов/женщин*** не звучит вовсе; в Р.п., насколько я представляю, склоняются обе части

Comment: Если запутались, спросите у ИИ: http://morpher.ru/SummaPro.aspx :)

Comment: Того, кто говорит "24 котов", я бы посадил под арест на 24 сутки! ;)

Answer (score 1):

- 20: вижу двадцать женщин и двадцать котов
- 21: вижу двадцать одну женщину и двадцать одного кота
- 25,26,27,28,29: вижу двадцать пять женщин и двадцать пять котов
- 22,23,24: it's tricky, and different sources give different answers.

  - According to gramota.ru, `я вижу двадцать два кота` - http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&start=45
  - According to http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1008, neither  `я вижу двадцать два кота` nor `я вижу двадцать двух котов` is correct. You should rewrite the sentence to avoid this.
  - https://hinative.com/ru/questions/4667834 : three different Russians gave three different answers
  - Conclusion: there is no consensus. If you believe in gramota.ru, use `я вижу двадцать две женщины и двадцать два кота`.

Answer (score 1):

Числительные небольшого количества (два, три и четыре) согласуются по одушевлённости – винительный падеж в зависимости от одушевлённости совпадает с **именительным или родительным**:

> Тургенев увидел **два пятна** случайных пешеходов. [И. Ф. Анненский. Вторая книга отражений (1909)]

Однажды, проезжая мимо одной из них, мы увидели **двух уток**. [В. Г. Короленко. Мороз (1900-1901)]

Однако в этом случае, по крайней мере с некоторыми одушевлёнными существительными, в частности, обозначениями животных, возможны колебания в пользу формы **именительного падежа**:

> Когда мы с ним сговаривались, с моим свояком, мы не одну, а три бутылки выпили, полночи гудели и он написал: взял **две коровы** на прокорм на зиму за три бутылки, одну корову верну по весне, обязуюсь ― и подпись. [Ф. Светов. Мое открытие музея (2001)]
>
> Старший сын старика Кувычки, рассказывал его сосед по воронежской деревне, когда, женившись, отделился, получил **три лошади**. [А. Чудаков. Ложится мгла на старые ступени (1987-2000)]

Кроме того, **одушевлённость обычно не выражена** в составных числительных, заканчивающихся на числительные небольшого количества:

> А он сделал невидимыми **тридцать три человека**. [М. Сергеев. Волшебная галоша (1971)]
>
> В тот день мы, пионеры шестого класса «Б», вылили <водой из нор> **двадцать два суслика** и вышли на первое место по заготовке шкурок. [С. Василенко. Суслик (1997)]

В языке XIX в. одушевлённость сохранялась в таких контекстах:

> Окромя, что побил великое множество неприятеля, взял в плен офицера одного, рядовых **пятьдесят трех человек**. [И. Д. Панчулидзев. Документы (1812)]
>
> Отправив таким образом всех (шестьдесят нижних чинов и **двадцать двух арестантов**), он с старшим унтер-офицером поехал последним. [Н. И. Греч. Записки о моей жизни (1849-1856)]

Answer (score 0):

Если число, оканчивающееся на 2, 3 или 4 (но не на 12, 13, 14), является многозначным (то есть больше или равно 21), то винительный падеж [числительного] совпадает с именительным как для конструкций с одушевленными, так и для конструкций с неодушевленными существительными:

> Вижу 22, 23, 24 кота, женщины.

http://nekin.info/math/imya_chislitelnoye.htm

К рекомендации допускать иное в разговорной речи я бы отнёсся с осторожностью.